# Conditional probability and signal

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have 2 agents. There are projects whose return can be either good
or bad $(g,b)$ with probability $\vartheta $ and $1-\vartheta $
respectively. The true return is denoted with $R$. Each one receives a
signal about the project's return $\hat{R}_{i}$ where $i\in \left\{
1,2\right\} $. The signal works as follows
 $\Pr \left( \hat{R}%
_{i}=g|R=g\right) =\phi _{i}$  or $\Pr \left( \hat{R}_{i}=b|R=b\right) =\phi
_{i}$.

This implies that the signal correctly classifies the return (good or
bad) with probability $\phi _{i}$. Clearly $\phi _{i}>0.5$ for the signal
to be informative.

Using Bayes Rule:

$\Pr \left( R=g|\hat{R}_{i}=g\right) =\frac{\phi
_{i}\vartheta }{\phi _{i}\vartheta +\left( 1-\phi _{i}\right) \left(
1-\vartheta \right) }$

and $\Pr \left( R=b|\hat{R}_{i}=g\right) =\frac{%
\left( 1-\phi _{i}\right) \left( 1-\vartheta \right) }{\phi _{i}\vartheta
+\left( 1-\phi _{i}\right) \left( 1-\vartheta \right) }$.

Also $\Pr \left( 
\hat{R}_{i}=g\right) =\phi _{i}\vartheta +\left( 1-\phi _{i}\right) \left(
1-\vartheta \right) $.

My question is: Is it possible to define $\Pr \left( 
\hat{R}_{1}=b|\hat{R}_{2}=g\right) $. In words, using the information given
what is the probability the first to classify the project as good given the
second classifies it as good?

Comment: The signal is still informative if $\phi _{i}<0.5$. For example if $\phi_i=0$ then when receives signal $g$, one knows that the true return is $b$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional probability you want is given by

$$\Pr \left( 
\hat{R}_{1}=b|\hat{R}_{2}=g\right)=\frac{\Pr \left( 
\hat{R}_{1}=b,\hat{R}_{2}=g\right)}{\Pr \left(\hat{R}_{2}=g\right)}$$

You have calculated already that

$$\Pr \left(\hat{R}_{2}=g\right)=\Pr(R=g)\Pr(\hat{R}_2=g|R=g) +\Pr(R=b)\Pr(\hat{R}_2=g|R=b)$$
$$= \vartheta\phi _{2} + \left(
1-\vartheta \right)\left( 1-\phi _{2}\right).\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

The other probability is calculated in a similar way:

$$\Pr \left( 
\hat{R}_{1}=b,\hat{R}_{2}=g\right)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$=\Pr(R=g)\Pr(\hat{R}_1=b,\hat{R}_2=g|R=g) +\Pr(R=b)\Pr(\hat{R}_1=b,\hat{R}_2=g|R=b)$$
$$=\vartheta (1-\phi_1)\phi_2+(1-\vartheta)\phi_1(1-\phi_2)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ $$